# Row not showing up in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I tried inserting a row in a table using a php and HTML file in dreamweaver however it is not showing up when I refresh phpMyAdmin page?

PHP

```
    <?php

$username="root";
$database="conception";

mysql_connect("127.0.0.1" ,$username);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$query = "INSERT INTO order VALUES ('','Shirt','M','black','that photo','L','none','UL','none','Sharpiee','#E0E0E0','BIU','Lobster','bottom','L')";

mysql_query($query);
mysql_close();

?>
```

I also used "localhost" instead of 127.0.0.1 but that did not work aswell. When i press the button in my form first it showed mysql_connect error but then i removed the password as a perimeter and onCLick it moves to a blank page.

Comment: The `mysql` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the `mysqli` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used

Answer (score 2):

First of all don't use mysql extension any more, it's deprecated of PHP 5.5 and will be removed in future, so use mysqli or PDO extension instead. Second `mysql_connect()` function should have 3 parameters. Check it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php).

Answer (score 2):

`ORDER` is a MySQL reserved keyword. That word is used for doing [`ORDER BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html), an optimization method.

- **http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html**

Either wrap it in backticks or use another word for it (rename your column to "orders") which is OK.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `order` VALUES ...
```

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help during production testing.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

which would have signaled the error.

Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

---

**Footnotes:**

`mysql_*` functions deprecation notice:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [**MySQL API Overview**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

These functions allow you to access MySQL database servers. More information about MySQL can be found at » http://www.mysql.com/.

Documentation for MySQL can be found at » http://dev.mysql.com/doc/.

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

---

Look up DB connection method for `mysql_` functions:

- **http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php**

***From example #1***

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

From [`mysql_select_db`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php) - DB selection.

***From example #1***

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// make foo the current db
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('foo', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}
?>
```